# Laravel MIX_ variables don't work in production

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Laravel allows you to acess .env variables in javascript by prefixing the app with `MIX_`, my file looks like this:

```
APP_NAME="My app"
MIX_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

This works in development, however when I build the app for production the app name shows up as undefined. Is there some way to get around this issue?

Comment: have you cleared the caches?

Comment: @DilipHirapara The app was freshly built for production, I don't believe there would be any cache, correct me if I'm wrong. If that was the case, how would I do that for a production built app?

Comment: @chinloyal, ye it will cache... Do ```php artisan optimize``` and try again. regards!

Comment: Doesn't work @hmrneves

Comment: Where do you use your variable i mean app.js or etc? What do you Production? Laravel or your JS?

Comment: @mhrabiee I use it in my Javascript files

Comment: @chinloyal can you show sample of code you use? can you log it?